# How do I selectively replace only skin color in an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing

I want to change the color of human skin to blue, like in the movie Avatar. I have used the following code to determine skin color pixels and replace their color:

```
 /*
 R > 95 AND G > 40 AND B > 20 AND

    max{R, G, B} – min{R, G, B} >15 AND

    |R – G| > 15 AND

    R > G AND R > B

    OR

    R > 220 AND G > 210 AND B > 170 AND

    |R – G| <= 15 AND

    R > B AND G > B    */




    if(((red>95)&&(green>40)&&(blue>20)&&(red-green>15)&&(red>green)&&(red>blue))||((red>220)&&(green>210)&&(blue>170)&&(red-green<=15)&&(red>blue)&&(green>blue))){


        data[i]=255; 
            data[i+1]=100-(190-red); 
            data[i+2]=200-(190-green); 
            data[i+3]=255;


    }
```

This method is working well for fair color skin in face images I've downloaded:

[image]

but when I take an actual picture from the camera it's not coloring the whole skin, only parts:

[image]

Is there a way to replace skin color pixels for a range of skin tones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, perfect skin segmentation is an unsolved (or perhaps unsolvable?!) problem. If you don't have a requirement about including "too many" pixels, then you can open up your thresholds to colour "more" of the pixels with the blueish hue. However, you'll then run into problems with background pixels or clothing pixels being discoloured also. Already we see the painting in the background of your shot being coloured blue even though it's not skin. At that point, I think your only option would be to use a smarter segmentation technique (likely an adaptive technique) to choose skin-coloured pixels better.

Answer (score 0):

Using Quartz you can create an image defining a specific color range to replace with:

```
CGImageRef myMaskedImage;
const float myMaskingColors[6] = {124, 255,  68, 222, 0, 165};
myColorMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors (image,
                                        myMaskingColors);
CGContextDrawImage (context, myContextRect, myColorMaskedImage);
```

See [Masking an Image with Color](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHCADE)